# No typeTag available Error in scala spark udf

Tags: scala, apache-spark, type-conversion, udf

I am getting no typetag found for Seq[String] while compiling the following code

```
val post_event_list_evar_lookup: (String => Seq[String]) = (pel: String) => {
  pel.split(",").filterNot(_.contains("=")).map(ev => {
    evarMapBroadCast.value.getOrElse(ev.toInt, "NotAnEvar").toLowerCase
  }).filterNot(_.contains("notanevar"))
}
val sqlFunc_post_event_list_evar_lookup = udf(post_event_list_evar_lookup)
```

Error message I am getting is 
[image]
I am using scala 2.10.4. Same code compiles with out any error in scala 2.11.4. Can someone please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: What line is causing the issue?

Comment: Try to compile with `-Xlog-implicits`. Sometimes there can be conflicts if you import something more than once. Normally `TypeTag` for `Seq[String]` should be available.

Comment: @pedrofurla `udf` has context bound `: TypeTag` on arguments and return type of its function.

Comment: @Victor Moroz I have added the full error message. Can you see it once?.

Comment: Do you have answer for this?